# angular material design input field, prevent setting of focus to next input element on click of enter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-material

In angular material design is there a way to stop shift of focus to the next input element on click of enter?

I have a table and one column inside that table is the md-input-container. as soon as I type the data and press enter key, focus shifts to the second raw input box, is there a way to stop this focus to the next element?

Please see the below html code. This code is inside ng-repeat.

```
<td>
<md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block inline-input-box qty-inp" >
    <input automation-id="custom-id-{{$index}}" aria-label="line item quantity" ng-model="currentQty" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' ng-blur="callUpdateFunction(item)"/>
</md-input-container>
</td>
```

Comment: It should not focus next input on `enter`. Make sure you don't have any script doing that

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Please see second example of this official documentation https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input. When you hit ENTER key after client name input element it does take you to the next input element. I don't want this to happen and not sure how this will resolve my issue.

Comment: The only reason focus is moving to that field is because it's invalid and when you pressed enter it tried to submit the form. Fill in a valid value for email and then go back to client name and press enter after typing a name. Focus will now move to the next invalid field.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey, yes that sounds correct. I will start thinking in this direction now. may be some script is adding focus to the next field.

Comment: If you've any validation on your form field, pressing enter will try to submit the form and required fields will be focused if they are not filled as @Lex says